# Mockito: Is it bad practice to spy on a method within the system under test which relies on a HTTP request?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

From reading around, it appears generally bad practice and a sign of code smell when you have to spy on a method that is used by the current method you're unit testing.

For example, I have this method that I'm unit testing:

```
public MyResponseObject doStuff(MyRequestObject obj) {
    WebTarget tar = getServiceClient().target(obj.toString());
    Response res = tar.path(someURI).request().post(somejson);
    if(response.getStatus() == 200) {
        String jsonResp = response.readEntity(String.class);
        return convertToObj(jsonResp);
    }
}
```

One way I'm attempting to solve the above is by

1. Extracting the first two lines (WebTarget, Response) to its own method that returns a Response object.
2. Creating a mock of Response and stubbing readEntity to return 200 and readEntity to return "OK"

Here's the result:

```
public MyResponseObject doStuff(MyRequestObject obj) {
    Response res = sendRequest(obj.toString());
    if(response.getStatus() == 200) {
        String jsonResp = response.readEntity(String.class);
        return convertToObj(jsonResp);
    }
}

//extracted method
public Response sendRequest(String json){
    WebTarget tar = getServiceClient().target(someUrl);
    return res = tar.path(someURI).request().post(somejson);
}

//My unit test

//sut is the system under test, setup elsewhere
public void testDoStuff() {
    MyRequestObject request = ...;
    Response respMock = mock(Response.class);
    when(respMock.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);
    when(respoMock.readEntity()).thenReturn("OK");
    MyClass spy = spy(sut);
    Mockito.doReturn(respMock).when(spy).sendRequest(requestString);
    MyResponseObject  response = spy.doStuff(request);

    assertEquals(response.toString(),expectedResp);
}
```

If I do not stub this out, it attempts to do a real HTTP request and returns an invalid URL error because I'm not supplying a real one - I believe this is what I want because I want my unit tests to be independent of some external system.

Is there a better way I should be going about my unit testing?

Comment: what do you mean under `spy on method  that is used by the current method you're unit testing` ?

Comment: Hi Oleksandr - I updated my post with more detailed example. Hope this clarifies it at least a bit more.

Comment: You can either:
1) refactor your code - extract http transport lauer into separate layer. 
2) use integration testing to test http related stuff - use `wiremock` - it will mock you target service - for you code it will be transperent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes creating a spy of the class you're testing is bad practice, break the code you're mocking out into another class and mock that, i.e:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final MySender sender;

    public MyClass() {
        this(new DefaultSender());
    }

    public MyClass(MySender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public MyResponseObject doStuff(MyRequestObject obj) {
        Response res = sender.sendRequest(obj.toString());
        if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
            String jsonResp = response.readEntity(String.class);
            return convertToObj(jsonResp);
        }
    }

    public interface MySender {
        Response sendRequest(String json);
    }

    private static class DefaultSender implements MySender {
        public Response sendRequest(String json) {
            WebTarget tar = getServiceClient().target(someUrl);
            return res = tar.path(someURI).request().post(somejson);
        }
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    private MyClass testSubject;

    @Mock
    private MySender sender;

    @Mock
    private Response response;

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff() {
        String expectedResp = ...;
        MyRequestObject request = ...;
        MyResponseObject  response = testSubject.doStuff(request);

        assertEquals(response.toString(),expectedResp);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        testSubject = new MyClass(sender);
        when(sender.sendRequest(anyString()).thenReturn(response);
        when(response.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);
        when(response.readEntity()).thenReturn("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Is there a name for this pattern and do you have other suggestions I can look up for related problems? Is this the most common practice when you want to be able to unit test your methods properly?

Comment: I don't know about a pattern name but it does follow the "single responsibility principle", we split the responsibility of sending your request away from the responsibility of understanding the response. If you want to know how to write better unit tests I'd suggest spending a little time looking at TDD, if you want to write good tests it needs to be one of your main focuses during development and if you put the test first and spend time thinking about the test-ability of your code you'll probably find you naturally tend towards writing cleaner, simpler more comprehensible code.

Answer (score 1):

Spying an object you are testing has been communicated to me as bad practice, but these warnings come with little to no explanation backing it up.  I'm sure, like anything else, it can definitely be abused.

What I have noticed when testing a method that calls another method of the object being tested, that it is better if you can knock out testing of both methods at the same time.  While you could mock the second method, to make the testing of the first method easier, you'll still need to go back at some point and test the second method.  Personally I support mocking the second method if it leads to cleaner test code.  Basically its an option that the universe gives you, and it should not be ruled out for all cases.

In your scenario, my personal preference would be to mock the `WebTarget` object, versus creating a second internal method.  The main reason for this is that you will have to go back and test the second method anyways, so might as well tackle it now.  But if you find that your code could be cleaner by separating those first two lines into their own method (or class) because it is re-usable code that is used multiples times, then of course split it out into its own method.  In this case, the architecture of the code itself (and not of the testing requirements) dictate the code structure.

When mocking the `WebTarget`, in this case, it involves with dealing with the builder methods, e.g. `.path(someURI).request().post(somejson)`, which each have to get mocked accordingly.  So that's a bit of a pain.  If I was doing this, I would probably use integration testing over unit testing if possible.  That is to say, have the server that is being contacted up and available so that I can test against it.  In our test environment, all the servers remain up so that we can do leverage more integration tests over unit-tests. As the environment grows, this might not be an option, but right now it is and it leads to cleaner integration-tests that knock out a lot of code coverage in less tests.